# After updating android level from 32 to 33, Logcat getting indefinite loop and app frozen

Tags: android-studio

After updating latest android compileSdkVersion 33 app Frozen and multiple tasks running in logcat

Error in Logcat:

> None of [android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] in
> {android.permission-group.CAMERA=[android.permission.CAMERA],
> android.permission-group.CONTACTS=[android.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
> android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS],
> android.permission-group.LOCATION=[android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION],
> android.permission-group.NOTIFICATIONS=[android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS],
> android.permission-group.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL=[android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
> android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO],
> android.permission-group.READ_MEDIA_AURAL=[android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO]}